# Deploy a TCP Server in Elastic-beantalk using python

Tags: python, sockets, amazon-web-services, tcp, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy a `tcp` server written in python using `ThreadedTCPServer`.

**Its possible to run this TCP server in beanstalk?**

I don't want to use or change the `WSGI` server.

A temporal solution I have implemented is to create a image that have installed the `tcp` server and when it starts, it launches the server automatically. My beanstalk uses a custom `ami` to create new instances.

Yet, doing it this way, I can't use the benefits of beanstalk(log, git `aws.push`, etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `container_command` to start your server process.

I've done this with some back-end processes that run alongside my `WSGI` server, but I don't see why you couldn't just do it without a WSGI server too.

Here's my .ebextensions/appname.config file:

```
container_commands:
  01_kill_old_server:
    command: "pid=`ps -aefw | grep 'myserver.py' | grep -v ' grep ' | awk '{print $2}'`; kill -9 $pid > /dev/null 2>&1 "
    ignoreErrors: true
  02_start_server:
    command: "nohup python ./myserver.py > foo.out 2> foo.err < /dev/null &"
```

Each time you deploy with `git aws.push` it will kill the old process and start a new process from your new code.

Here's `container_commands` documentation:  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-container_commands